# How to define properties on a type defined by a javascript function?

Tags: typescript

I need to work with a legacy library that's plain old javascript, but which I have renamed with a .ts extension so I can gradually refactor it. This is mostly working, but the code does one thing that Typescript doesn't like:

```
function TestUtil() {}

TestUtil._startTime;
```

and the Typescript compiler is complaining that `Error  TS2339  (TS) Property '_startTime' does not exist on type 'typeof TestUtil'.`

I cannot find any syntax that will let me indicate that `TestUtil` should be treated like `any`, so that I don't get this kind of compilation error. How can I get around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `TestUtil` to be defined as `any` (which is probably not recommended), you can do this as such:

```
const TestUtil:any = function() {}
```

Comment: I'd like to give it strong typings, but for now I just want to use it as is, but without the compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the `_startTime` var be declared inside the function?
The function `TestUtil` has no var _startTime declared inside of it

Maybe convert it to a class and set `_startTime` as an static attribute?

```js
class TestUtil() {
    static _startTime: any;
}
```

Comment: Yes it should. There's a lot of weird syntax and a fair number of bugs. Indeed the point of converting this to Typescript is to get the compiler's help in finding and fixing them.